# Pass a parameter across views - Django

Tags: django, forms, url, parameters, view

I have the following scenario:

I have created globalModels (Season, Team, Player, Referee). Also, I have created seasonalModel (SeasonTeam, SeasonPlayer, SeasonReferee) as I want to record statistics from a Team every particular season, same with Player and Referee) and also I will aggregate statistics from every SeasonTeam into the globalModel Team.

I am building platform for administration. So I have next urls:

**adminSite.urls**

```
url(r'^$', views.homeAdmin, name='homeAdmin'),
url(r'^addGlobal/', include('globalModels.urls', namespace='addGlobal')),
url(r'^addSeasonal/', include('seasonalModels.urls', namespace='addSeasonal'))
```

**globalModels.url**

```
url(r'^$', admin_views.addGlobal, name='addGlobal'),
url(r'^addSeason/', views.addSeason, name='addSeason'),
url(r'^addPlayer/', views.addPlayer, name='addPlayer'),
url(r'^addTeam/', views.addTeam, name='addTeam'),
url(r'^addReferee/', views.addReferee, name='addReferee')
```

Now, in order not to have to choose the season (foreignKey in every seasonalModel) everytime I want to add a new seasonalModel, I want to make a first step of choosing the season, and then let the administratos choose between adding a seasonalTeam, seasonalPlayer...

How would you accomplish this? I have thought about 2 possibilities:

**FRONT END**

Display with a list of the seasons registered as divs and with JS get the id that the administrator has click on:

```
{% for season in seasons %}

        <div id="{{ season.season }}" class="adminButton chooseSeason ">
            {{ season.season }}
        </div>

{% endfor %}
```

And then pass it inside the url:

```
$(".chooseSeason").click(function (){
    var season = $(this).attr('id');
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/admin-site/addSeasonal/" + season + "/";

 })
```

In this case, I have my:

**seasonModels.py**

```
url(r'^chooseSeason', admin_views.addSeasonalChooseSeason, name='addSeasonalChooseSeason'),

url(r'^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/', admin_views.addSeasonal, name='addSeasonal'),

url(r'^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/addTeam/', views.addSeasonalTeam, name='addSeasonalTeam'),
url(r'^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/addPlayer/', views.addSeasonalPlayer, name='addSeasonalPlayer'),
```

But I am missing how to make the register the namespace properly:

**addSeasonal.html**

```
<div id="addTeamButton" class="adminButton">
    <a href="{% url 'admin-site:addSeasonal:addSeasonalTeam:season1-season2' %}"> Añadir Equipo </a>
</div>

<div id="addPlayerButton" class="adminButton">
    <a href="{% url 'admin-site:addSeasonal::addSeasonalPlayer:season1-season2' %}"> Añadir Jugador </a>
</div>
```

*'addSeasonalTeam' is not a registered namespace inside 'admin-site:addSeasonal'*

Any idea on how to avoid this problem?

**BACK END**

Pass as a ModelForm the available seasons registered, and use the submitted as a parameter passed with the request in order to filter in the view that will be used to add the new object in the database

In this case, if season as a globalModel is a charField, how can I force the form to be a list of option with the seasons registered insted of a charField expecting an input?

Sorry for the long post, I hope you could understand my intention and help me.

Thanks in advance!

PR

Comment: I only skimmed over your question, but at first guess, I think you might want a form wizard. I would recommend looking into these: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: Wow it seems like it is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks a lot man! That's another tool in the box :)